# Heroku command info. Producing incorrect info?

Tags: java, heroku, cloud, scaling

I want to have **one free dyno** working for my JAVA test application.

I suspect that I already have this and that there is a bug in heroku info.
However the app is really slow. The strange thing is that only I use the app so very little load is applied. The app should be fast and optimized as it's a small sample app done with spring roo as per the heroku tutorial. If run locally on my laptop the performance is magnitudes better than heroku.

What do you say is it simply a bug in the `heroku info` command or do I have 0 dynos?

$ heroku info **//Shows 0 dynos**

```
....
Dynos:          0
Workers:        0
Repo size:      75M
Slug size:      61M
Stack:          cedar
Data size:      32k
Addons:         Basic Logging, Basic Release Management, Shared Database 5MB
```

$ heroku ps **//I interpret this as 1 dyno; correct?**

```
Process       State               Command
------------  ------------------  ------------------------------
web.1         up for 30m          java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/depend..
```

$ heroku scale web=1 **//Try to force 1 dyno**

```
Scaling web processes... done, now running 1
```

$ heroku info **//Stills shows 0 dynos**

```
....
Dynos:          0
Workers:        0
Repo size:      75M
Slug size:      61M
Stack:          cedar
Data size:      32k
Addons:         Basic Logging, Basic Release Management, Shared Database 5MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `heroku info` doesn't show the dyno but if `heroku ps` shows one then you are using one.  It shouldn't be slow, except that the first request to each page will cause the JSP to be compiled.  But after it is compiled things should be fast.  For comparison, here is the Spring Roo Pet Clinic app running on Heroku:
http://blazing-window-406.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks very much. I am using the same app Pet Clinic :). Unfortunately you link is equally slow as mine :(. Of course when the app has been unloaded/first time it is slow. But if I look with firebug your, and mine, app is extremely slow. here is my firebug analysis 467ms (262ms waiting and 204ms receiving)

Comment: Just as a reference http://localhost:5000/pets?page=1&size=10 30ms your project http://blazing-window-406.herokuapp.com/pets?page=1&size=10 489ms. So a laptop without any run time optimization is 16times faster than a real server seems strange. Ok add 20ms for internet connection or something and the laptop still will be a magnitude faster.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thanks. I will do a new performance test later to see if there is a difference on another internet connection. I have 4ms ping time here to a test server, but it could be fun to see if different ISP have different heroku loading times. I will also try to set up my own server and test it over internet to see how much latency internet brings

Comment: Heroku is using Amazon's East data center.  So depending on where you are, that could cause network latency.